# Iphone : Video playing at startup doesn't quit

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, startup

i made a video playing when my app loads however it doen't quit after playing even if you prees "Done". What am i doing wrong?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Video Logo Final" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0);
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
[theMovie play];
[super viewDidLoad];  }
```

Also, i made a try to put the same code in "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" but i get a warning at "[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];"
Ay ideas about that?

p.s. As you probably guessed i am very new to programming, any help would be really appreciated...

Comment: and you can read tutorial here: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/play-video-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-in-ios-3-0-and-3-24-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to register for a notification.

The way I do it is:

```
// Register for the playback finished notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self 
    selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) 
    name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
    object: theMovie];
```

Change the parameters to fit however it should in your app.

Here's the [documentation for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification).

Also, if it's not "quitting" after playing (even when hitting the "Done" button), it sounds like you need to remove the `theMovie` MPMoviePlayerController and associated view from the view you originally added it to.